# Change icon size and text size

Tags: text

I have a 28 inch 4k monitor. How can I resize the icons and text size. could only find 3 sizes at settings > universal access > display > sizes normal/large/larger

I Ubuntu it is possible to set the size in percentages.

Is this setting in development or maybe there is an app available for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Those settings you refer to are not available in Elementary. I've tried changing icon size without success. But i use [Elementary Tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) to change text size and that works perfectly. It's enough for me. Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark it as solved.